# How to delete diacritics from a string in C#?

Tags: c#, string

I have a string  -

```
125DF885DF44é112846522FF001
```

I want to remove **é** from the string. When I search online I get solutions to remove the accents from **é** and returns **e**.

The *diacritic character* can come anywhere in the string and not in fixed place, also can be more than one.

How do I remove those?

Comment: What did you tried? Did you tried using a foreach loop and build a new string? Or `String.Replace("é", "");`?

Comment: I would recommend you tackle the problem from the other side. What characters are allowed? Then filter to keep only those, maybe with a `Regex`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

```
string s = "125DF885DF44é112846522FF001";
string s1 = s.Replace("é","");
```

Comment: OMG, It didn't even occur to me to even try the replace method. Thank you so much.

Comment: If you have more than just é, you can put those in array or list and loop thru that collection and replace every diacritic. Regex is also nice approach as @Jeremy Lakeman mentioned

Comment: You, probably, want `string s1 = s.Replace("é","e");` - note `"e"` - to *substitute* `"é"` by `"e"`, not totally remove  `"é"`

Answer (score 2):

In general case, we can remove symbols of unicode `NonSpacingMark` range:

1. We turn each symbol into pair: symbol + its mark(s) (that's the diacritics)
2. We remove marks
3. Combine symbols back

**Code:**

```
using System.Linq;

...

string source = "125DF885DF44é112846522FF001";

string result = string.Concat(source
    .Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD)
    .Where(c => CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) != 
                UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark))
  .Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC);
```